# Can somebody walk me through this Haskell function (State monad related)?

Tags: haskell, state, monads

```
tick :: State Int Int
tick = get >>= \n ->
       put (n+1) >>= \y ->
       return n
```

I'm confused as to how `put (n+1)` has any effect on the end result of this function at all. It seems like this function should return the initial state unchanged. I'm trying to run through this in my mind, but I keep running out of room to hold things in place. :\

If someone could walk me through the evaluation of this function, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ...How is puts updating the state in the first place? It seems to just be sitting there doing nothing...

Ah, now I understand your question. You're wondering how `put` (and `get`) work, right?

Maybe an example in JavaScript will help (a language with actual mutable state):

```
var s; // mutable state
function get() { return s; }
function put(x) { s = x; }

function tick() {
    var n = get();
    put(n + 1);
    return n;
}
```

I hope this illustrates that, while `n` doesn't change, the internal state still will get updated. If you execute `tick()` twice, the state will be incremented twice.

To get back to Haskell, here's the full definition of (the relevant parts) of the `State` monad:

```
newtype State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }

instance Monad (State s) where
    return a = State $ \s -> (a, s)
    m >>= k  = State $ \s -> let
        (a, r) = runState m s
        in runState (k a) r

get   = State $ \s -> (s, s)
put s = State $ \_ -> ((), s)
```

Now try to expand your `tick` example even further by manually inlining `>>=`, `return`, `get` and `put`. Hopefully it will get more clear how State works.

Comment: I beat you by a whole 5 seconds! It's odd how I tend to figure out things on my own /after/ I've asked the question. I appreciate the responses! :)

Answer (score 7):

You're completely right. The "result" of `tick` "function" is the initial value of the state.

Now of course, `tick` isn't the real "function", but a computation that can read and write *state* before producing a result.
In this case, the *state* is updated, but you're still returning the original value of the state:

```
-- 4 is the inital state
ghci> runState tick 4
(4, 5)
-- 4 is the result of the tick computation, 5 is the updated state
```

In this case, since you're never inspecting the state again inside `tick`, you're not seeing the changed state. However, if some other computation happens after `tick`, it can see the updated state.

For example, doing `tick` twice (the second one will read the updated state):

```
-- 4 is the inital state
ghci> runState (tick >> tick) 4
(5, 6)
-- 5 is the result of the tick computation executed twice,
-- 6 is the updated state
```

Comment: What I don't understand is how this is happening. How is the state getting updated, but the return value staying the same? How is puts updating the state in the first place? It seems to just be sitting there doing nothing.

Comment: Indeed, the state is being updated, but the return value, `n` stays the same. See my other answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795785/can-somebody-walk-me-through-this-haskell-function-state-monad-related/1796544#1796544

Answer (score 5):

it might help to write it using `do` notation

```
tick :: State Int Int
tick = do
    n <- get    -- get the state
    put (n+1)   -- save an incremented state
    return n    -- return the original state
```

while the `put (n+1)` does not impact the result of the computation, it does alter the state that is held within the state monad.

Comment: That doesn't really help. I desugared my example so I could try to understand it. I'm trying to figure out what is going on below the surface here to make this state change happen.

Comment: fair enough, I would've posted the definitions of get and put, but I guess thats been done.

Comment: That wouldn't have helped either. :p

I had already looked at those definitions as deeply as possible, it it was that one crucial detail that was escaping my eyes. It isn't your fault, it's my fault for not being able to word a question correctly.